# how to convert a file containing hex format to binary format using lua

Tags: lua

```
00004b0 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff 00ff
00004c0 0000 fc01 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
00004d0 ffff ffff 0089 0019 0801 0101 0000 0000
00004e0 0000 0000 0000 3130 0000 0009 ff02 00ff
00004f0 0000 0000 0000 ff00 ffff ffff ffff ffff
0000500 008b 001c 0a03 0001 0000 ffff ffff 94ff
0000510 b325 c55f 076f 000b ff02 acff ffa2 a733
0000520 fe19 28be 0000 ffff ffff ffff 008b 002a
0000530 0a05 0001 0000 001d df03 94e6 b325 c55f
0000540 076f 000b 0002 ac06 ffa2 a733 fe19 28be
0000550 0e00 0000 0000 0000 000b ff03 00ff 0000
0000560 0000 0000 ff00 ffff ffff ffff ffff 008b
0000570 002a 0a08 0001 0000 001d df03 94e6 b325
0000580 c55f 076f 000b 0002 ac09 ffa2 a733 fe19
0000590 28be 0e00 0000 0000 0000 000b ff03 00ff
00005a0 0000 b300 03b0 ff02 ffff ffff ffff ffff
00005b0 008b 002a 0a0b 0001 0000 001d df03 94e6
00005c0 b325 c55f 076f 000b 0002 ac0c ffa2 a733
00005d0 fe19 28be 0e00 0000 0000 0000 000b ff03
00005e0 00ff 0000 b300 03b0 ff02 ffff ffff ffff
00005f0 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
```

I am actually having file like this how to convert into binary like 0x11 to 0001 0001

Comment: It's not clear what exactly it is that you're trying to do. Is the source file the text you've posted here, or is what you've shown merely a textual representation of the bytes of the file? Do you want to store the data represented by this text as bytes in a file as strings of boolean text, or as the bytes this textual data represents?

Comment: how to convert bin values stored in bin file to hexadecimal in lua 5.1.Is there any function present

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by that. So, your file is a binary file, but how do you want to interpret the stream of bytes within that file?

Comment: my file is a binary file whose values can't be read in vi editor .How to change those values in the file to hexadecimal in lua5.1?

Comment: another one how to print binary string like 00010010 from that type of file like which string format used be used for printing.my output is seen like this ��������

Comment: "*my file is a binary file whose values can't be read in vi editor*" Well... yeah. Your file is a binary file. I don't know VI, but my understanding of it is that it's a *text* editor. If you want to look at the contents of a binary file, you need a binary file viewer, not a text editor. Are you saying that you want to overwrite the binary file with a textual version of itself?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it, using `gmatch` to select each byte in the string.

Then you convert the hex byte to it's number value and process that with a function to get the binary digits.

```
    local hexfile = '0011 ffff'

    local function bytetobin(n)
        local t = {}
        local d = 0

        d = math.log(65535) / math.log(2)

        for i = math.floor(d), 0, -1 do
            t[#t + 1] = math.floor(n / 2^i)
            n = n % 2^i
        end

        return table.concat(t)
    end

    local function hextobin(hex)
        local num = tonumber(hex, 16)            
        local bin = bytetobin(num)            
        local result = bin:gsub("()", {[5]=" ", [9]=" ", [13]=" "})

        return result
    end

    for line in hexfile:gmatch('([^\n]+)') do
        local binarystring = ''

        for v in line:gmatch("(%x+)") do
            binarystring = binarystring .. hextobin(v) .. ' '
        end

        print(binarystring)
    end
```

Output:

```
 0000 0000 0001 0001 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

`bytetobin` function from:[love2d user: Zorg](http://%20https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=84988&start=10) modified to produce leading 0s